# Do any poskim recommend giving a conditional divorce?

Tags: marriage, halacha-theory, posek-psak-decisor-ruling, divorce

For someone who married without a halachic pre-nuptual agreement, are there any halachic authorities who recommend giving a conditional get (bill of divorce) which stipulates that it would go into effect if/when one of the parties wishes to end the marriage?

Comment: Why would one do this? Why would having given a halachic pre-nuptual agreement (what did the agreement say?) have anything to do with this?

Comment: "For someone who married without a halachic pre-nuptual agreement": do you mean a _k'suba_? (I'm guessing not, but then it'd be good if you [clarify](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/36843/edit) what you *do* mean.)

Comment: In the time of King David, men would give a *Get* before going to battle in case they never return.

Comment: @BackseatChazan but they didn't have an issue of a biya being koneh

Comment: @DoubleAA to avoid aguna issues, I suppose. If he made a prenup, he can force a get when he needs it.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin What kind of prenup? And why would he need to force a get?

Comment: @DoubleAA oops, it's supposed to be a she. Although I think the OP is confusing the two types of Agunas

Comment: I think a postnup would do the trick, e.g., http://www.jlaw.com/Forms/postnuptial.html

Answer (score 5):

I doubt you would find any Halachic authorities who recommend giving a conditional Get.

The reason being that after giving such a Get, he may not seclude himself with his wife.

If he did seclude himself - and there are witnesses, then even if she subsequently fulfills the condition on the Get, she is only *possibly divorced* - הֲרֵי זוֹ סְפֵק מְגֹרֶשֶׁת.

This defeats the purpose of what you're trying to achieve, and possibly aggravates the situation.

Find this in the Rambam [הלכות גרושין - פרק שמיני](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_02017.html#HtmpReportNum0033_L2):

> **ב:**  כָּל **הַמְגָרֵשׁ עַל תְּנַאי** בֵּין שֶׁאָמַר מֵעַכְשָׁו בֵּין שֶׁאָמַר אִם יִהְיֶה וְאִם לֹא יִהְיֶה **הֲרֵי זֶה לֹא יִתְיַחֵד עִם אִשְׁתּוֹ** כָּל זְמַן שֶׁלֹּא נִתְקַיֵּם הַתְּנַאי אֶלָּא בִּפְנֵי עֵד. וַאֲפִלּוּ עֶבֶד וַאֲפִלּוּ שִׁפְחָה חוּץ מִשִּׁפְחָתָהּ אוֹ בְּנָהּ קָטָן מִפְּנֵי שֶׁאֵינָהּ בּוֹשָׁה מִלְּשַׁמֵּשׁ בִּפְנֵיהֶם. וְהַדָּבָר יָדוּעַ **שֶׁאִם נִתְיַחֵד עִמָּהּ בִּפְנֵי שְׁנֵי עֵדִים כְּאֶחָד אֲפִלּוּ נִתְקַיֵּם הַתְּנַאי אַחַר כָּךְ הֲרֵי זוֹ סְפֵק מְגֹרֶשֶׁת**. שֶׁמָּא בְּעָלָהּ וּבָטֵל הַגֵּט כְּמוֹ שֶׁיִּתְבָּאֵר בַּהֲלָכוֹת אֵלּוּ:‏

And the Shulchan Aruch also Paskens like this in [סימן קמח - דין המגרש בגט ישן, והמגרש בתנאי, ושלא יתיחד עמה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01974_part_5.html#HtmpReportNum0029_L2)

> **ב:** כָּל **הַמְגָרֵשׁ עַל תְּנַאי**, בֵּין שֶׁאָמַר: מֵעַכְשָׁו, בֵּין שֶׁאָמַר: אִם יִהְיֶה וְאִם לֹא יִהְיֶה, הֲרֵי זֶה **לֹא יִתְיַחֵד עִמָּהּ כָּל זְמַן שֶׁלֹּא נִתְקַיֵּם הַתְּנַאי**, אֶלָּא בִּפְנֵי עֵד, אֲפִלּוּ עֶבֶד וַאֲפִלּוּ  שִׁפְחָה, וּבְיוֹצֵא וְנִכְנָס סָגֵי, חוּץ מִשִּׁפְחָתָהּ אוֹ בְּנָהּ הַקָּטָן, מִפְּנֵי שֶׁאֵינָהּ בּוֹשָׁה לְשַׁמֵּשׁ בִּפְנֵיהֶם. וְהַדָּבָר יָדוּעַ **שֶׁאִם נִתְיַחֵד עִמָּהּ בִּפְנֵי שְׁנֵי עֵדִים** כְּאֶחָד, וְרָאָה הוּא וְהִיא  אוֹתָם, **אֲפִלּוּ נִתְקַיֵּם הַתְּנַאי אַחַר כָּךְ, הֲרֵי זוֹ סְפֵק מְגֹרֶשֶׁת**, שֶׁמָּא בְּעָלָהּ וּבִטֵּל הַגֵּט, וְיִתְבָּאֵר בְּסִימָן שֶׁאַחַר זֶה: